# I cannot seem to append my else if statement

Tags: if-statement, append, contains

if I try to type in the "oz" or "OZ" the else if statement doesnt seem to proceed and I do not know why. Any help would be appreciated! THANKS!!!

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String Ma = "mass" + "MASS";
    String La = "oz" + "OZ";

        System.out.println("Hi, what are you trying to find?");
        System.out.println("mass");
        System.out.println("vol");
        System.out.println("temp");
        System.out.println("sphere");
        System.out.println("density");
        String convert = input.nextLine();

        if (Ma.contains(sb.append(convert))) {
            System.out.println("You are trying to convert mass.");
            System.out.println("Type the unit of measurement you are trying to convert to.");
            System.out.println("If you are trying to find mass type mass.");
            System.out.println("pound");
            System.out.println("ounce");
            System.out.println("ton");
            System.out.println("gram");
            System.out.println("mass");
            String mass = input.nextLine();
        }
        else if (La.contains(sb.append(convert))) {
                System.out.println("34223412351Type the number of oz.");
                double oz = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz / 16 + " lb.");
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz / 32000 + " ton.");
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz * 0.02835 + " kg.");
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz * 28.35 + " g.");
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz * 2835 + " cg.");
                System.out.println(oz + " oz equal to " + oz * 28350 + " mg.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the stringbuilder you can directly use Ma.contains(convert) and La.contains(convert), this will run the if else properly.

The reason it's not running for oz in your case is that the string builder is appending 'oz' twice. 
1. When it checks to see in Ma
2. When it checks to see in La
So at La your sb contains 'ozoz', which is why the else if is never run.

If you need to use the stringbuilder here use sb.append after reading the string from scanner and not in the if conditions